# Solving for an unknown modulus

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have the following:

$$ab \pmod x = 1.$$

$a$ and $b$ are known. Is there an efficient procedure to find the largest possible value of $x$?

**Edit:** What if $a$ and $b$ are too large to factor efficiently though?

Comment: You're missing the obvious.

Answer (score 3):

$ab-1\equiv0\pmod x$.  So what's the largest factor of $ab-1$?